# Creating a Matrixlist package

Tags: packages, package-writing, parcolumns

I haven't been able to find a suitable package that does what I want. The closest is `parcolumns` and I've spent several hours trying to understand TeX programming and the `parcolumns` style. While I got the most of it I've tried to tweak it and just can't get it to do what I want.

I'm curious if anyone either knows of a package or can write one up quickly that does the following:

1. You give it a `\\` terminated list just like enumerate and the number of columns;
2. It internally groups the list by number of columns. (a,b,c,d,e) with `columns=2` will be grouped as ((a,b,c),(d,e));
3. It then creates m rows (`\hbox`es, depending on the number of elements and column size). The nth row contains an `\hbox` of the nth element in each group. This creates a matrix

   > a d
   >      b e
   >      c
4. Each element in the row tries to distribute itself evenly along the horizontal BUT if on element overlaps the next it will "push" it INSTEAD of overlapping it (and this will continue until there is no need to push);
5. No gaps between rows AND no end gap on last column (so one has to get the width of the largest element in the last column and set the column size to that).

The point here is we have a matrix of boxes BUT if the horizontal content of one box is larger than the space it is given it will simply shift the adjacent box over to make room for it BUT if not it will align in a distributed manner.

Hopefully that makes sense and there is already a package that does this. With `parcolumns` I have two issues: When my elements are horizontally too large (even if just a little) they overlap the next column and I have to manually push that next element over (which may cause a chain reaction).

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\scrollmode


\begin{document}

\newcommand{\drawrect}[1]{\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture} \fill (-#1,-1) rectangle (#1,1);\end{tikzpicture}}}

\noindent\fbox{\hbox to \linewidth{%
\drawrect{1.5}\hspace*{\fill}\drawrect{1.5}\hspace*{\fill}\drawrect{1.5}\\}}
\fbox{\hbox to \linewidth{\drawrect{2}\hspace{0.2cm}\drawrect{1.5}\hspace{1.2cm}\drawrect{1.5}\\}}
\fbox{\hbox to \linewidth{\drawrect{2.5}\hspace{0.2cm}\drawrect{1.5}\hspace{0.2cm}\drawrect{1.5}\\}}
\fbox{\hbox to \linewidth{\drawrect{2.4}\hspace{0.4cm}\drawrect{1.5}\hspace{0.2cm}\drawrect{1.5}\\}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is an example situation

1. Note that the first element of row 3 "pushes" or overlaps into the 2nd element of row.
2. This causes the 2nd element to be offset by some amount (user specified). The 3rd element does not change positions though.
3. In row 4, the first element is slightly smaller BUT note that the 2nd element is aligned with the one right above it BECAUSE it snaps to that position to for visual reasons.
4. Also, if you were to add a fixed amount of whitespace to each element in the last column then you would end up causing problems (depends on how you set it up though). I want to remove this issue. To fix it we basically have to remove the whitespace so that at least one element in the last column has no whitespace. Hence we just "substract" the appropriate amount of whitespace from all columns and then at least one will have no whitespace. Note that this is only for calculating the column spacing. Essentially we just compute (`\linewidth` + x)/#columns where x is the smallest amount of whitespace from the set of cells in the last column. This effectively increases the `\linewidth` by the unused whitespace in the last column.

Comment: Can you clarify the first point (enumerate doesn't use `\\ ` separators it uses `\item`) and the last point (you say the width of the last column is that of its widest entry, but what of other columns? widest entry in that column?) finally you say the entries are hboxes, but you compare with paracolumns which takes multiline material rather than hboxes as its items?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle 1. I "obviously" meant a tabular(but basically the &'s are "computed"(actually I was just thinking of a simple list. What I really want to do is avoid having to use special macros to designate the a new element. Maybe &\\ could be used to mean start new "element")

Comment: 2. In parcolumns the last column will have extra space. Why? Because the column size, by default, is evenly distributed as \linewidth div numcolumns. But suppose your last column has elements that use almost no width? This will mean that there will be a lot of white space at after these elements AND visually it will look like the whole matrix is off center to the left. The goal is to shift the box back to the right to center the matrix. Do this this all you have to do is shift the whole matrix by the smallest amount of whitespace that exists in the last column.

Comment: if it were a tabular (and an earlier, presumably related question) asked about multicol and longtable then the columns would always be vertically aligned and one wide entry in column n  would push the entire next column to the right, but your description above makes it sound as if you want the displacement just to affect that one row?

Comment: 3. parcolumns does not use hboxes internally for it's rows. You can use them or not. by hbox I really just mean a self contained row. I'm thinking that what I want would be implemented a set of rows rather than a set of cells or set of columns. parcolumns implements it as a set of columns. Basically I would think it would be implemented as \vbox{\hbox{}\hbox{}...}

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, I do not want the whole column to shift. Basically I am only thinking in terms of rows. One row will not effect the other in any way. The way I achieve this effect now is to add some hspace to my elements in parcolumns and this will shift the element that are being overlapped with by some space so it is no longer being hit by the previous element in the row.

Comment: On the other hand it one might want to try to align previous cells along the column if they are close for visual purposes(I do this manually when I have to add space to two adjacent rows). I'll try to add an MWE.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle One way to think about this is that I want the row elements to snap along column guide lines. The lines are distributed to either "equally along linewidth" OR to cells above or below. The new environment will try to snap to these guide lines to get the best visual look. If you have one cell that is slightly shifted horizontally to one below it, it is not very aesthetically pleasing. There should be no problem moving one slightly over to align them vertically.

Answer (score 2):

Well,... visually aligning boxes depending on rows above and below isn't really the tex way (not impossible, but....) I'd go for a layout like this, where the entries are just equally spaced in the rows.

[image]

To get each of the boxes (or if you want, just the boxes in the last column) to be natural width rather than a specified width of short, use `\begin{minipage}{\xxx}` for fixed boxes and `\begin{varwidth}{\xxx}` for the boxes on at least the last column
where `\xxx` is textwidth divided by number of columns, adjusting for any space or rules between columns. `varwidth` from the package of the same name is like `minipage` but sets the box to a narrower width of possible.

If you use `varwidth` in the last column, the entire construct will not be full width, but can just be centered (with `\centering` in that case) as I think you wanted.

If that layout is acceptable, the other syntactic issues, like calculating column width and entering cells in column major rather than row major order can be sorted if need be.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\scrollmode


\begin{document}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\noindent X\dotfill X

\newcommand{\drawrect}[1]{\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture} \fill (-#1,-1) rectangle (#1,1);\end{tikzpicture}}}

\def\onerow#1{\par\noindent\fbox{%
  \dimen0=\textwidth
  \advance\dimen0-2\fboxsep
  \advance\dimen0-2\fboxrule
\hbox to \dimen0{#1}}}


\onerow{\drawrect{1.5}\hfill\drawrect{1.5}\hfill\drawrect{1.5}}
\onerow{\drawrect{2}\hfill\drawrect{1.5}\hfill\drawrect{1.5}}
\onerow{\drawrect{2.5}\hfill\drawrect{1.5}\hspace{0.2cm}\drawrect{1.5}}
\onerow{\drawrect{2.4}\hfill\drawrect{1.5}\hspace{0.2cm}\drawrect{1.5}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unfortunately your 2nd row is very unaesthetic to me compare your 2nd row with mine. Surely you would agree mine is more visually appealing? It should not be difficult at all to the alignment to previous rows. Simply keep a history of the previous column snap. (e.g., for each column we have a variable that represents the offset from equal distribution(linewidth/3 or whatever). Generally this is 0. But when we have an overlap we set this to how much we had to push the cell to avoid the overlap. If there was no overlap it gets set to 0. Cells will just use this value in there hspace.

Comment: For example, when we go through row one we set up offset_k = 0. When we go through the 2nd row we use offset_k for the kth column offset. In this case since there is no overlap the offsets will be 0 and you will end up like my examples' 2nd row. When we get to the 3rd row we see the first element is overlapping into the 2nd by some amount. We take this amount it extends into the 2nd column and add some user defined amount then set offset_2 to be this amount. This will cause the 2nd element of the 3rd row to be offset by this amount AND the 4th row's 2nd element(almost)

Comment: The only trick is to make it "fuzzy" so that we have to reset the offsets or change them depending on their magnitude. For example, if the offset_k was very large but our push for the current row was very small we might want to use our user defined amount + the new offset. (sort of ignore the previous offset_k because it was much larger than we new one)

Comment: "Surely you would agree mine is more visually appealing?" well no actually, all the others look like the 2nd item is centred between the 1st and 3rd, and so that one looks misplaced. But personal preferences are personal:-)

Comment: In any case, it shouldn't be hard to do... and if I actually could understand the tex programming I probably could do it myself ;/ Maybe if you could write up a simple package environment where it would do the distribution evenly BUT by using those offset_k's then I might be able to modify them to in the proper way.

Comment: Hehe, well, I prefer my version. Maybe it is because I have an example in mind and your version doesn't look right when they are not solid rectangles. The good news is that such a package could easily switch between the two simply forcing the offset_k's to be 0.

Comment: In my case, I want to keep the "matrix" look(cells are evenly distributed both horizontally and vertically) EXCEPT fix the overlap problem that will occur.(i.e., you can't have both). Every cell prefers to be distributed evenly if it can but if it can't the next best option is to align itself with to it's neighbors or some visually acceptable way. These are not difficult calculations to do but I just don't know enough tex to do it properly and really don't have all the time in the world to figure it out ;/